# Print variable in different php file

Tags: php

Hi I have shopping cart and i want print item name in different php file. I try this.

```
<?php
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
        {
            $total = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
                $product_cart = $values["item_name"];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td> <?php session_start(); $_SESSION['produktik'] = $values["item_name"] ;  ?>

                    <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $values["product_price"]; ?>€</td>
                    <td><?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2); ?>€</td>
                    <td><a href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">X</span></a></td>
                </tr>
```

and second php file is

```
    <pre>
 <?php  
 session_start();

 echo $_SESSION['produktik'];
 ?>

    </pre>
```

Comment: You don't describe what you're actually hoping to achieve or what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: And obviously you need `session_start();` in all files that use sessions.

Comment: instead of starting the session in this line ->                    <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td> <?php session_start(); $_SESSION['produktik'] = $values["item_name"] ;  ?>
 try to start it as the first line of code after opening php...

Comment: Thank you i will try it. The problem is that second php file dont wants to accept this session

Comment: Generally `session_start()` must be called before sending output to the browser.  In your second file, you have a `<pre>` tag before your session start.  That's likely why it's not working